# Java RegEx to convert self closing xml tags to closing tags

Tags: java, regex

I am not soo good in RegEx. Can somebody help me to to replace

```
<MessageParam name="0" desc="Source Queue" />
```

with

```
<MessageParam name="0" desc="Source Queue"></MessageParam>
```

using regular expression

Comment: You should try using JDom instead.

Comment: [don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regex to match:

```
(<\s*MessageParam[^>]*)/\s*>
```

Replacement string:

```
$1></MessageParam>
```

You may need to escape the `\` character (add an extra `\` before it).

I assume `>` does not appear in the value for the attributes, and the XML is valid.

More generalized version:

Regex to match:

```
<\s*([^\s>]+)([^>]*)/\s*>
```

Replacement string:

```
<$1$2></$1>
```

For this one, I'm not sure of all the assumptions that I have made. But I still assume `>` does not appear in the value for the attributes, and the XML is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure if XML parser can change the type of closing tag. It is better to use XML parser to do so if possible.

Comment: For those of you looking for the inverse of this question, you can use the following code to replace open/close empty tags with self-closing tags. Find: `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>` Replace it with: `<$1/>` (Thanks to https://www.thetopsites.net/article/51312414.shtml)

Answer (score 6):

Regex

```
<(\w+)(.+?)/>
```

replace with

```
<$1$2></$1>
```

Comment: This just really helped me, as the accepted answer produced some occasionally strange results

Comment: This doesn't work on nested DOM elements, unfortunately.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Just use this in Notepad++ with the find and replace feature and you are done :)

Comment: saved me hours of wasted effort

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void format(String xmlNode) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(<MessageParam[^>]*)(\\s*/>)");
    Matcher mattcher = patt.matcher(xmlNode);
    while (mattcher.find()){
        String result = mattcher.replaceAll("$1></MessageParam>");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple `replaceAll` in String class will do, not sure why you go through all the trouble of writing Pattern/Matcher loop.

Comment: nhahtdh - I don't understand how a replaceAll will help if i have multiple strings with different 'desc'

Comment: `xmlString.replaceAll("(<MessageParam[^>]*)(\\s*/>)", "$1></MessageParam>");`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
xmlString.replaceAll("<(\\w*:*\\w+)/>", "<$1></$1>");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).